# Calculations in c# and converting string to double

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I am trying to calculate currency in a console application, so I need to convert a string to a decimal number. I can `Convert.ToInt32` but cannot `Convert.ToDouble` here is an example, the user will input 7 digits as an answer. When I can make the console app I will develop this in a winform. Any help will be great thank you.

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first rate");
        NGNRate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the  Master rate");
        TM_USD_ZAR = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(NGNRate / TM_USD_ZAR);
```

Comment: [Double.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx).And if you are treating currency, i'd rather use `decimal` instead of `double`

Comment: Why can't you use `Convert.ToDouble()`?

Comment: Try to use a ',' or a '.' as decimal separator while converting to double

Comment: hi waka It won't implicitly convert to double. It says I may need to cast I, so I entered `NGNRate = Convert.ToDouble(double)(Console.ReadLine());` which didn't work either.

Comment: Fruchtzwerg I tried using separator with no joy. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Decimal.Parse`, documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first rate");
        decimal NGNRate = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the  Master rate");
        decimal TM_USD_ZAR = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(NGNRate / TM_USD_ZAR);
```

Comment: Thank You @berserck that makes sense and works. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToDouble()` depends on regional settings and decimal separator if you have `.` as a decimal and you enter `,` your conversion will  not succeed

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first rate");
 var NGNRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

 Console.WriteLine("Please enter the  Master rate");
 var TM_USD_ZAR = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

 Console.WriteLine(NGNRate / TM_USD_ZAR);
```